# Root Volume Expansion AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, redhat

We need to instantiate an ec2-instance(RHEL) which has 10 GB of space mounted on root, we tried several time but usable disk always show 6 GB.

Please see the screenshot.

Can somebody tell how to use this remaining 4 GB disc space and would appreciate if there is a way to use this remaining disc space in existing root partition.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not have 10 GB of space mounted on root. You have a 10 GB block device (/dev/xvda) with a 6 GB root partition (/dev/xvda1) on it. So you still have 6 GB of space mounted on root.

To remedy this, assuming you are using the Linux ext4 filesystem (which is the default on RHEL6), follow these instructions to expand the partition (which involves a reboot) and then expand the filesystem within it:
**https://askubuntu.com/a/119458/2800**

With those instructions, replace `/dev/sda` with `/dev/xvda`, and `/dev/sda1` with `/dev/xvda1`.

If you are using XFS, replace `resize2fs` with `xfs_growfs`.